# Submit private app to the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

There's a service without free registration or something like that. Clients of this service have login and password. This service wants to develop an iOS app and distribute it in the App Store. This app won't be useful for regular users. Is it possible to submit this app in the App Store?

I understand that there are options like enterprise developer account, but for some reasons the developer wants to use regular account and regular app store.

I've read App Review Guidelines and didn't find any restrictions which require application be useful to anyone.

Of course test login will be provided for reviewer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store guidelines. 

Comment: You *might* (or might not) encounter a problem should the reviewer test your app and can't actually use it for anything. That said, I agree with the off-topic-ness, it's impossible to methodically solve your problem, and you're at best fishing for anecdotes.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, look at concur & office 365 as examples

Comment: And do you know how to do so ?